# unable to paste content on yahoo body using iMacros

Tags: imacros

i have a piece of imacros code for sending out Yahoo eMails which works great. But except for pasting content in the body field. I have tried a few other methods using imacros, but i can't get this part to work.

Here is my code. Appreciate any help. :)

```
VERSION BUILD=844 RECORDER=CR
SET EMAIL "test@test.com"
SET PASS "password"
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
URL GOTO=https://login.yahoo.com/?.src=ym&.intl=us&.lang=en-US&.done=https%3a//mail.yahoo.com
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:mbr-login-form ATTR=ID:login-username CONTENT={{EMAIL}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:mbr-login-form ATTR=ID:login-signin
SET !ENCRYPTION NO
WAIT SECONDS=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD FORM=ID:mbr-login-form ATTR=ID:login-passwd CONTENT={{PASS}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:mbr-login-form ATTR=ID:login-signin
WAIT SECONDS=3
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=ID:yui_3_16_0_ym19_1_*
WAIT SECONDS=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:to-field CONTENT=test@gmail.com
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:subject-field CONTENT=test
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:rtetext
TAG POS=5 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=ID:yui_3_16_0_ym19_1_*
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Event recording mode (iMacros Sidebar - Manage Tab - Settings) for entering the message body? I tried a quick recording myself and found that the following two commands together were successful in filling the message body:

```
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV:nth-of-type(9)>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(7)>DIV>TABLE>TBODY>TR:nth-of-type(2)>TD>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)" BUTTON=0
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV:nth-of-type(9)>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(7)>DIV>TABLE>TBODY>TR:nth-of-type(2)>TD>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)" CHARS="this is a test"
```